# Is speaking in tongues evidence that someone is saved?

Tags: 1-corinthians, spiritual-gifts

Is speaking in tongues evidence that someone is saved? And is it a sign that one has been baptised in the Holy Ghost? In my church that seems to be what they believe, that as a believer you must speak in tongues. In 1 Corinthians 14:1-33 the apostle Paul gave a description of how it's supposed to be done. But in my church everybody will speak without interpretation and I'm seriously confused.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for your question. Pleae do not forget to take the tour to understand how this site works. I have edited your question. If you do not agree with my editing please press edit and change it. Tour link: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Some churches teach that this is true, but most don't. Questions on this site need to be focused on the interpretation of specific passages, but doctrinal and practical questions can be asked at [christianity.se].

Answer (score 3):

1 Corinthians 12:

> 30
> Do all have gifts of healing? Do all speak in **tongues**? Do all interpret?

No. No. No.

The very next verse, 1 Corinthians 13:

> 1 If I speak in the **tongues** of men or of angels, but do not have love, I am only a resounding gong or a clanging cymbal.

Is speaking in tongues an evidence that someone is save?

No. The performance of speaking in tongues is neither necessary nor sufficient for eternal salvation.

Comment: Good simple answer!

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking multiple questions here. You are asking for clarification about salvation, baptism in the Holy Ghost, the flow during church assembly, and praying in tongues. These are wonderful questions!

If you have been born again, you have the privilege of asking God about *anything* as you study His word. He will never lie to you. You will know the truth, and the Truth will make you free (John 8:32).

Momentarily, let's read literally what the Bible says without relying on man-made commentary, doctrinal tradition, or personal experience. Also let us limit our scope to only tongues.

##### What does the Bible say about tongues?

According to Jesus,
Mark 16:17:

> And these signs shall follow them that believe; In my name shall **they
> cast out devils; they shall speak with new tongues;**

According to Paul,
1 Corinthians 14:5 (ESV):

> **Now I want you all to speak in tongues**, but even more to prophesy. The one who prophesies is greater than the one who speaks in tongues, unless someone interprets, so that the church may be built up.

1 Corinthians 14:18 (ESV):

> **I thank God that I speak in tongues more than all of you.**

1 Corinthians 14:39 (KJV):

> Therefore, brethren, desire earnestly to prophesy, and **do not forbid
> to speak with tongues.**

##### A personal prayer language is a different God-given gift than the *manifestation gifts* of the Spirit described in 1 Corinthians 12

The manifestation gifts that pertain to tongues are: the "gift of (various) tongues" and "interpretation of tongues".

1 Corinthians 12:10:

> To another the working of miracles; to another prophecy; to another discerning of spirits; to another **divers kinds of tongues**; to another the **interpretation of tongues**:

##### Conclusion

According to the Bible in the New Testament, believers will speak in new tongues and it should not be forbidden. This does **not** mean speaking in tongues is required to enter the Kingdom. Jesus is the door (John 10:9). Praying in tongues is something that can be received in faith, or not. However, according to the Bible, believers **shall** speak with new tongues.

When the perfect has come (when Jesus comes back) prophecy and tongues will cease (1 Cor 13:8-10) because revelation of Christ will be complete and the body of Christ won't need to learn about Christ through these means anymore.

There have been many traditions of man about the Holy Spirit, I'm probably holding a ton of wrong beliefs about Him as I type this, but He's a person. You may always ask Him *anything* directly. He will never tell you anything contrary to the word.